# How to construct an HTTP post with Groovy HTTPBuilder RESTClient

Tags: groovy, httpbuilder

The post example from [the docs](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/) does not function with http-builder 1.7.1.

```
def msg = "I'm using HTTPBuilder's RESTClient on ${new Date()}"

def resp = twitter.post(
        path : 'update.json',
        body : [ status:msg, source:'httpbuilder' ],
        requestContentType : URLENC )

assert resp.status == 200
assert resp.headers.Status
assert resp.data.text == msg

def postID = resp.data.id
```

The exception is

```
wslite.rest.RESTClientException: No such property: body for class: wslite.http.HTTPRequest
```

Trolling the API, it is not obvious how you are supposed to construct the post correctly.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the exception it looks like you are using the groovy-wslite library and not HTTPBuilder.  If that is the case, the following should work:

```
def resp = twitter.post(path: 'update.json') {
    urlenc status: msg, source:'httpbuilder'
}
```

Comment: The groovy http-builder library uses wslite under the covers, but only for the `RESTClient` class.  The `HTTPBuilder` class in the http-builder library uses apache http builder.  Confused yet?

Comment: ah, ok.  If you `println twitter.getClass()` what does it display?  If the answer is wslite.rest.RESTClient then my answer should still work.

Comment: This clued me in to the embarassingly simple problem: an incorrect import statement!  I should have been using `groovyx.net.http.RESTClient`

Answer (score 3):

Faced a hard time in calling page with httpbuilder which requires login. Hence sharing my working code.

```
    def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://localhost:8080/")
        def query = [ username: "testUsername", password:"testPassword"]
            http.request(Method.POST,ContentType.URLENC) {
                uri.path = "user/signin"
                uri.query = query
                headers['Content-Type']= "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
                response.success = {resp-> println resp.statusLine }
            }
```

Hope this helps.